# RL ppo alrorithm: understanding value loss and entropy plot

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, pytorch

I'm implementing a computer vision program using PPO alrorithm mostly based on [this work](https://github.com/ikostrikov/pytorch-a2c-ppo-acktr-gail)

Both the critic loss and the actor loss decrease in the first serveal hundred episodes and keep near 0 later(actor loss of 1e-8 magnitude and critic loss of 1e-1 magnitude). But the reward seems not increasing anyway.

I'm using first conv2 layers of VGG-m with 2 linear layers behind, for both the actor and critic parts, except different final output dimension. The network input  is 3x255x255, and becomes 32x14x14 before feeded into the linear parts. For every episode I'm using 20~40 frames of a video sequence to do 4 full updates.

How should I interpret the loss and reward graphs? I think the losses decrease too quickly then too small may be a sign that I have set some thing wrong.

[image: actor loss]

[image: critic loss]

[image: reward]

```
# in main-training function:
while train_eps < args.train_epochs:
    for seq_id in range(num_seqs):
        train_step = train_eps * num_seqs + seq_id
        reward_seq = 0
        img_path_list, gt_list = train_dataset[seq_id]
        for frame_idx in range(1, len_seq-1):
            # get an image patch as state s
            value, a_chosen, action_log_prob = ppo.choose_action(s)
            # ..
            # calclulate r
            reward += r
            pair_mem.store_tuple(s, a_chosen, r, value, action_log_prob)
        if frame_idx == len_seq - 2:
            # calculate discounted reward and save to mem
        # if get enough samples in mem (~900 pairs)
            # update(mem, batch_sz)
        reward_seq = reward_seq * 1.0 / (len_seq - 1)


def update(self, pair_mem, batch_sz):

    a_loss_steps, c_loss_steps, total_loss_steps = 0, 0, 0
    entropy_steps = 0

    for i_step in range(self.update_steps):

        patch_rb, a_out_rb, r_rb, v_rb, alp_rb, dr_rb = pair_mem.get_rand_pairs(batch_sz)

        s = torch.tensor(patch_rb).float().to(device)
        a = torch.tensor(a_out_rb).float().to(device)
        returns = torch.tensor(r_rb).float().to(device)
        action_log_prob_old = torch.tensor(alp_rb).float().to(device)

        adv = dr_rb - v_rb
        if self.use_norm_adv:
            adv = (adv - adv.mean()) / (adv.std() + 1e-5)
        adv = torch.Tensor(adv).to(device)

        value_preds = torch.Tensor(v_rb).to(device)

        values, action_log_prob, dist_entropy = self.evaluate_action(s, a)
        action_log_prob = action_log_prob.to('cuda:0')
        dist_entropy = dist_entropy.to('cuda:0')
        ratio = torch.exp(action_log_prob - action_log_prob_old)
        surr1 = ratio * adv
        surr2 = torch.clamp(ratio, min=1-self.eps, max=1+self.eps) * adv
        a_loss = -torch.min(surr1, surr2).mean()

        if self.use_clipped_value_loss:
            value_pred_clipped = value_preds + \
                                 (values - value_preds).clamp(-self.eps, self.eps)
            value_losses = (values - returns).pow(2)
            value_losses_clipped = (value_pred_clipped - returns).pow(2)
            c_loss = 0.5 * torch.max(value_losses, value_losses_clipped).mean()
        else:
            c_loss = 0.5 * (returns - values).pow(2).mean()

        self.opt.zero_grad()
        if self.use_entropy_loss:
            total_loss = a_loss + c_loss*self.value_loss_coef - dist_entropy*self.entropy_coef
        else:
            total_loss = a_loss + c_loss*self.value_loss_coef
        total_loss.backward()
        self.opt.step()

        a_loss_steps += a_loss.item()
        c_loss_steps += c_loss.item()
        total_loss_steps += total_loss.item()
        entropy_steps += dist_entropy.item()

    return a_loss_steps/self.update_steps,\
           c_loss_steps/self.update_steps, \
           total_loss_steps/self.update_steps, \
           entropy_steps/self.update_steps
```

And also I noticed the `dying ReLU` issue. May it be related to my problem? Since my c-loss starts at ~1e4 magnitude.

Edit:
Now I changed some logic of my state-action logic, modified my actor and critic net, added grad clipping operation. This is what I get now.

[image: entropy seems almost not decrease]
[image: value loss]
[image: reward]

And you can see form these graphs, the training process looks at least better than my previous version. But comparing with graphs in [Understanding PPO plots](https://medium.com/aureliantactics/understanding-ppo-plots-in-tensorboard-cbc3199b9ba2), there may still exists problems.

I can't understand why the value loss should increase first and then decrease. Also I think the entropy should increase from the expression of the total loss while should decrease considering the reward converges, is it a balance that entropy decreases in the plots of the above post?

Can anyone explain those expected graphs with loss funcions?

Comment: your reward looks suspiciously cyclic ... which would indicate some plateau-y condition - which your agent is oscillating around - the value loss could have just learned that space, explaining why value loss ~ 0.  If you check what the game state looks like at say ... those low points I wonder if they are the same. Could you post some code for the training loop procedure?

Comment: I also found this. Yes I am using about 9k small video snippets, which is near the oscillating period in the graph. The cyclic then makes sense that my network actually never changes after first hundreds of learning. I will post some of my main training code.

Comment: Interesting about the dead relu - have tried you using LeakyRelu? Also, how are you initializing your layers? are you using the same initialization as in that repo - as I noticed these RL problems are particularly sensitive to that...   Another thing is gradient clipping before the optimizer.step() which is in the original code  - is there a reason you are not doing that?

Comment: I'm tring LeakyRelu now. And previously I just initialized the later parts of my critic network, using normal distribution, to get a ~1e1 output at the very first. While using pytorch default initialization method to the later parts of my actor network since the entropy is about ~3e1 at the very first. Finally, I modified the code by multi versions and the grad clipping operation is left. Perhaps that's the key. Thanks for advicing. I will give more feedback.

Comment: @PavelSavine. If my entropy decreases too slow, to which side should I adjust my beta?